Issues Installing v5.75+ on Lando / Drupal 10 and 11
I have run into an issue installing versions of CiviCRM above 5.74.
I will paste the full backtrace below, but first here are some facts:
I first tried installing the latest version with Drupal 11 and I then ran into the same issue installing it with Drupal 10.
I am using PHP 8.3 and MySQL 8.0, both to be ready to make the switch to Drupal 11.
I am trying to install the site locally on a x86 Mac with Lando / Docker.
I was able to successfully install Drupal 10 and CiviCRM 5.74.
I see that the EntityRepository was added in 5.75 and I suspect that is the issue. I get this error when trying to run the installer. I also tried installing 5.74 and upgrading. I see the issue each time I run drush cr.
I have only found one other reference to this issue, Upgrading to 5.75 causes PHP error.
Any advice will be appreciated!
Here is the error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Civi\Schema\EntityRepository::getEntity(): Argument #1 ($entityName) must be of type string, null given, called in /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php on line 278 and defined in /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Schema/EntityRepository.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php(278): Civi\Schema\EntityRepository::getEntity(NULL)
#1 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php(71): CRM_Core_DAO_Base::getEntityDefinition()
#2 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php(490): CRM_Core_DAO_Base::getTableName()
#3 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php(154): CRM_Core_DAO::getLocaleTableName()
#4 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO/Base.php(18): CRM_Core_DAO->__construct()
#5 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/BAO/Domain.php(61): CRM_Core_DAO_Base->__construct()
#6 /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Config.php(95): CRM_Core_BAO_Domain::getDomain()
#7 /app/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php(60): CRM_Core_Config::singleton()
#8 /app/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Routing/Routes.php(23): Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->initialize()
#9 [internal function]: Drupal\civicrm\Routing\Routes->listRoutes()
#10 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(146): call_user_func(Array)
#11 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/ProxyClass/Routing/RouteBuilder.php(83): Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#12 /app/web/core/includes/common.inc(454): Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Routing\RouteBuilder->rebuild()
#13 /app/web/core/includes/utility.inc(41): drupal_flush_all_caches(Object(Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel))
#14 /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Commands/core/CacheRebuildCommands.php(60): drupal_rebuild(Object(Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Drush\Commands\core\CacheRebuildCommands->rebuild(Array)
#16 /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(276): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#17 /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(212): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback(Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#18 /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/CommandProcessor.php(175): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter(Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#19 /app/vendor/consolidation/annotated-command/src/AnnotatedCommand.php(387): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, Array, Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandData))
#20 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(279): Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1094): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(342): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(193): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(110): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 /app/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(40): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#26 /app/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(140): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run(Array)
#27 /app/vendor/bin/drush.php(119): include('/app/vendor/dru...')
#28 {main}
  thrown in /app/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Schema/EntityRepository.php on line 38

